# Verify IPv6 address is Subnet-Router anycast address in C

Tags: c, network-programming, ipv6

[RFC 4291](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4291#section-2.6.1) specifies Subnet-Router anycast address.

```
2.6.1.  Required Anycast Address

The Subnet-Router anycast address is predefined.  Its format is as
follows:

|                    n bits                      |   128-n bits   |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|                   subnet prefix                | 00000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------------+----------------+

The "subnet prefix" in an anycast address is the prefix that
identifies a specific link.  This anycast address is syntactically
the same as a unicast address for an interface on the link with the
interface identifier set to zero.
```

Examples: [`fd42:6356:abfe:1549::`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/371) [`fd36:773e:6b4c:47cb::`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597225/python-getting-an-ipv6-socket-to-receive-packets-destined-for-the-subnet-router).

How to verify in C code that some address is Subnet-Router anycast address?

BTW I need to know prefix, thus these examples expect it's the "default" 64 bit, but there is no default prefix, right? (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=684009, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1609898, https://source.isc.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=dhcp.git;a=commitdiff;h=140612c8cb51825fdf9e5723afb78c997117ab2c;hp=c2e5ee2882d6d9dba5e7227d432552a3ab75b9e2).

Comment: [See this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/34172/8499) about using other tan `/64` networks. You also want to consider the [Reserved IPv6 Subnet Anycast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2526), and you need a network large enough to respect the required 128 reserved anycast addresses. You also use `/127` networks (two addresses) for point-to-point links to prevent Ping Pong attacks, and you cannot have the reserved anycast addresses for that: [RFC 6164](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6164).

Comment: @ricky (since you replied to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76321/configure-virtual-lan-with-subnet-router-anycast-address-to-debug-ping-bug), could you care to review my patchset https://github.com/iputils/iputils/pull/376 which tries to fix https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/371?